# Remove space between x axis and bars in bar plot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I've created a grouped bar chart with pgfplots and pimped it with the help of a few questions here. The only remaining problem is that my x axis is at -1, whereas the bars start at 0. How do I get the x axis to 0? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar
 width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt] plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em)
 };},
}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 ybar,
 enlargelimits=0.25,
 legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
 anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
 ylabel={fluorescence},
 symbolic x coords={TAL HH,TAL TZ5,TAL TZ6},
 xtick=data,]
\addplot+[ error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit, y dir=both, y explicit,] coordinates {
(TAL HH, 76879917) -=(0,22531389) +=(0,21159986)
(TAL TZ5, 27228112) -=(0,5414108) +=(0,6209091)
(TAL TZ6, 63135992) -=(0,14518424) +=(0,17525052)};
\addplot+[ error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit, y dir=both, y explicit,    ] coordinates {
(TAL HH, 58917246) -=(0,8508086) +=(0,9412441)
(TAL TZ5, 21851813) -=(0,2888807) +=(0,2381172)
(TAL TZ6, 55715124) -=(0,11839828) +=(0,5571992)};
\addplot+[ error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit, y dir=both, y explicit,] coordinates {
(TAL HH, 22860014) -=(0,1997756) +=(0,1974453)
(TAL TZ5, 1825717) -=(0,906132) +=(0,809597)
(TAL TZ6, 15720028) -=(0,5089543) +=(0,4310822)};

\legend{TAL,positive,negative}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `enlargelimits=0.25`, you need to specify how much `pgfplots` should introduce slack space around the plot. For example, using

```
enlarge y limits={0.25,upper},
enlarge x limits=0.25,
```

instead of `enlargelimits=0.25` will give

[image]

otherwise the extra space is added to both sides of the plot for both axis.