# aligning plots in pgf plots and a couple other associated questions

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am fumbling my way through pgfplots. I have 3 plots on a page. I have a few issues:

1. The bars in the plots are floating above the axes to various degrees. How do I anchor the bars down to the axis?

2.I want more spacing between the upper barcharts and the lower barchart, how do i achieve this? I tried \vspace to no avail.

Please see my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[online]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
      x=1.5cm,
      bar width=.4cm,
       %enlarge x limits=1,
      xticklabels={0,1,2,$\geq3$},
      title= \textbf{\# of cats per week for whom I was directly repsonsible},
      title style={align=center,text width=5.2cm},
      enlargelimits=.15,
      ylabel=\textbf{Frequency},
      xlabel=\textbf{\# of cats},
      xtick={0,...,3}, % To make sure the tick labels match the data points
      xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
      nodes near coords,
      nodes near coords align={vertical}] % Make all letters the same height so they align properly
        \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
            (0, 4)
            (1, 9)
            (2, 26)
            (3, 33)
        };
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\hspace{1cm} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
          xshift=4em,          
          x=1.5cm,
          bar width=.4cm,
           %enlarge x limits=1,
          xticklabels={0,1,2,$\geq3$},
          title= \textbf{Avg \# of cats from whom I obtained a complete physical exam and presented the results to the Vet was:                 
          },
          title style={align=center,text width=7cm},
          enlargelimits=.15,
          ylabel=\textbf{Frequency},
          xlabel=\textbf{\# of cats},
          xtick={0,...,3}, % To make sure the tick labels match the data points
          xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
          nodes near coords,
          nodes near coords align={vertical}] % Make all letters the same height so they align properly
            \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                (0, 3)
                (1, 17)
                (2, 20)
                (3, 31)
            };
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{5pt}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
          xshift=4em,          
          x=1.5cm,
          bar width=.4cm,
           %enlarge x limits=1,
          xticklabels={0,1,2,$\geq3$},
          title= \textbf{Avg \# of procedures (e.g., lumbar punctures) that I was allowed to perform was:},
          title style={align=center,text width=7cm},
          enlargelimits=.15,
          ylabel=\textbf{Frequency},
          xlabel=\textbf{\# of procedures},
          xtick={0,...,3}, % To make sure the tick labels match the data points
          xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
          nodes near coords,
          nodes near coords align={vertical}] % Make all letters the same height so they align properly
            \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                (0, 53)
                (1, 8)
                (2, 7)
                (3, 3)
            };
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: See here for your first question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208659/32374; for your second, simply introduce an extra empty line between the end of the first picture and the vspace, and between the vspace and the last tikzpicture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208681/32374, you need to change how you specify the enlargement of the axes. Instead of `enlargelimits=0.15`, use

```
enlarge x limits=.15,
enlarge y limits={0.15, upper},
```

Then, I had to specify also `ymin=0`. I also edited your axes to use the `ybar` style instead of the plots, since this sets up the tick marks and such so they (IMHO) look a little better.

For the second issue, you simply need to move the second graph to a new paragraph by inserting some extra blank lines. Then your `\vspace` will work. See the fixed example below. Note that I "minimized" your preamble a bit for this example.

Finally, the most recent version of [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) as of this writing is `1.11` - is there a reason you don't use this one?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
        x=1.5cm,
        bar width=.4cm,
        %enlarge x limits=1,
        xticklabels={0,1,2,$\geq3$},
        title= \textbf{\# of cats per week for whom I was directly repsonsible},
        title style={align=center,text width=5.2cm},
        % Change these lines
        enlarge x limits=.15,
        enlarge y limits={0.15, upper},
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        %Change the above lines
        ylabel=\textbf{Frequency},
        xlabel=\textbf{\# of cats},
        xtick={0,...,3}, % To make sure the tick labels match the data points
        xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical} % Make all letters the same height so they align properly
    ]
    \addplot[black, fill=none] coordinates {
        (0, 4)
        (1, 9)
        (2, 26)
        (3, 33)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hspace{1cm}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
        xshift=4em,
        x=1.5cm,
        bar width=.4cm,
        %enlarge x limits=1,
        xticklabels={0,1,2,$\geq3$},
        title= \textbf{Avg \# of cats from whom I obtained a complete physical exam and presented the results to the Vet was:
        },
        title style={align=center,text width=7cm},
        % Change these lines
        enlarge x limits=.15,
        enlarge y limits={0.15, upper},
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        %Change the above lines
        ylabel=\textbf{Frequency},
        xlabel=\textbf{\# of cats},
        xtick={0,...,3}, % To make sure the tick labels match the data points
        xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical}
    ] % Make all letters the same height so they align properly
    \addplot[black, fill=none] coordinates {
            (0, 3)
            (1, 17)
            (2, 20)
            (3, 31)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1in}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
        xshift=4em,
        x=1.5cm,
        bar width=.4cm,
        %enlarge x limits=1,
        xticklabels={0,1,2,$\geq3$},
        title= \textbf{Avg \# of procedures (e.g., lumbar punctures) that I was allowed to perform was:},
        title style={align=center,text width=7cm},
        % Change these lines
        enlarge x limits=.15,
        enlarge y limits={0.15, upper},
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        %Change the above lines
        ylabel=\textbf{Frequency},
        xlabel=\textbf{\# of procedures},
        xtick={0,...,3}, % To make sure the tick labels match the data points
        xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical} % Make all letters the same height so they align properly
        ]
    \addplot[black, fill=none] coordinates {
    (0, 53)
    (1, 8)
    (2, 7)
    (3, 3)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```